# Javsacript for loop giving out weird results

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I wrote a simple for loop to perform some DOM manipulation based on the json response. Here's the code I have

```
 onSuccess: function(a) {
        var b = a.items.length;
        for (i = 0; i < b; i++)
          user_id = a.items[i].id;
          $('#user_id').checked = true;
          selectUserSettings(user_id);
        }      
    },
```

In one example I was working with, the resultset 'a' had 14 items in them. The for loop, when adding a breakpoint, shows the value of i at 0,1,2,2,3,2,3,4,2,3,4,5... Basically it resets and begins at 2 and goes upto 1 additional index before doing it over again... What am I doing wrong here ?Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most probably because of this line `for (i = 0; i < b; i++)` when `i` is declared without a `let` or `var` keyword , it is in global scope.

Change this to

```
for (let i = 0; i < b; i++)
```

Also if my understanding is correct you want to use `user_id` variable to access the element. If it is so then change

```
   user_id = a.items[i].id;
  $('#user_id').checked = true;
```

to

```
let user_id = a.items[i].id;
$('#'+user_id).checked = true;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. Should it strictly be let or should var work as well ? just asking since I have to support some older browsers that don't handle let too. The second part $('#user_id') was a typo on my part.

Comment: in that case use `var`

Comment: For a `let` keyword compatibility reference [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Browser_compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Browser_compatibility)